# Using ScreenManager with separate py and kv files for each screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm making a calculator app and I want to be able to use separate kv and py files for each screen, I haven't found any documentation or tutorial about this and [the only answer I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102528/how-to-add-for-each-screen-an-own-py-and-kv-file) doesn't give a code example so I'm not sure how to implement it. Also the buttons on calc.kv send a callback to calc.py by referencing it in root so that could probably cause a problem because the root is screenmanager

If you try to open the calculator from the toolbar it will return this error message:

```
 screen = self.get_screen(value)
   File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1071, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "calc".
```

here is the code:

**calc.py**

```
from logging import root
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


prev = ""
expression = "" 
prox = "" 
class calc(Widget):
    pass
    out = StringProperty('')
    Window.size = (420, 200)
    Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
    
    
    
    def my_callback(self, inpt):
        global prev
        global expression
        global prox
        
            
        if inpt == "=":
            prox = str(eval(expression))
            self.out = prox
            expression = ""
            prev = prox
            
            
        elif inpt == "ac":
            expression = ""
            prev = ""
            prox = ""
            self.out = expression
        
        
            
        else:
            expression = prev + inpt
            prev = expression
            self.out = expression
        
         
        
                    
class calcApp(MDApp):  
    def build(self):
        def press(text):
            print("called: ", text)
    
        return calc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calcApp().run()
```

**calc.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

   

<calc>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        cols: 2
        size: root.width, root.height

        MDLabel:
            id: 'output'
            text: str(root.out)
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            halign: 'center'

        GridLayout:
                       
            cols: 5
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '1'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
                
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '2' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '3'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '-'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: 'ac'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '4'  
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '5' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '6'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '+' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: '('
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '7' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '8' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '9' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '*'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            
            MDFlatButton:
                text: ')'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '0' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '.'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: '/'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '**'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '='
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
```

**main.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

#: include calc.kv

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout

    ScreenManager:

        Screen:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDToolbar:
                    title: app.title
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

                ScreenManager:
                    id: screen_manager
                    calculator:
                        
                    

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '8dp'
            spacing: '8dp'

            Image:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '280dp', "200dp"
                source: "logo.png"
            
            ScrollView:
            
                MDList:

                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "calculadora"
                        on_release:
                            screen_manager.current = 'calc'
                            nav_drawer.set_state()
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'view-dashboard'
```

**main.py**

```
import calc
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "calculadora"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


MyApp().run()
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't defined any `Screen` with the name `calc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to the `<calc>` in the calc.kv file and instead of inheriting from the `Widget` class, inherit from the `Screen` class in the calc.py file. After that you need to load the calc.kv file in main.py using `Builder.load_file("calc.kv")` and then add the `calc()` `Screen` in your .kv with a function like `on_release`

**calc.py** (just change inheritance from `Widget` to `Screen` over here)

```
from logging import root
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


prev = ""
expression = "" 
prox = "" 
class calc(Screen):
    out = StringProperty('')
    Window.size = (420, 200)
    Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
    
    
    
    def my_callback(self, inpt):
        global prev
        global expression
        global prox
        
            
        if inpt == "=":
            prox = str(eval(expression))
            self.out = prox
            expression = ""
            prev = prox
            
            
        elif inpt == "ac":
            expression = ""
            prev = ""
            prox = ""
            self.out = expression
        
        
            
        else:
            expression = prev + inpt
            prev = expression
            self.out = expression
        
         
        
                    
class calcApp(MDApp):  
    def build(self):
        def press(text):
            print("called: ", text)
    
        return calc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calcApp().run()
```

**calc.kv** (just give a name to the class for reference)

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

   

<calc>:
    name: 'calc'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        cols: 2
        size: root.width, root.height

        MDLabel:
            id: 'output'
            text: str(root.out)
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            halign: 'center'

        GridLayout:
                       
            cols: 5
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '1'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
                
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '2' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '3'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '-'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: 'ac'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '4'  
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '5' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '6'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '+' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: '('
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '7' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '8' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '9' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '*'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            
            MDFlatButton:
                text: ')'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '0' 
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '.'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                text: '/'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            
            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '**'
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)

            MDFlatButton:
                
                text: '='
                on_press: root.my_callback(self.text)
```

**main.py** (just load calc.kv in the beginning)

```
import calc
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Builder.load_file("calc.kv")

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "calculadora"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv** (just import the calc class, and add its object to the manager)

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
#:import calc calc.calc

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout

    ScreenManager:

        Screen:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDToolbar:
                    title: app.title
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

                ScreenManager:
                    id: screen_manager
                    calculator:
                        
                    

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '8dp'
            spacing: '8dp'

            Image:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: '280dp', "200dp"
                source: "logo.png"
            
            ScrollView:
            
                MDList:

                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "calculadora"
                        on_release:
                            screen_manager.add_widget(calc())
                            screen_manager.current = 'calc'
                            nav_drawer.set_state()
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'view-dashboard'
```